# Android Studio / ¿Por Qué no puedo deslizar mi Recycler-View hacia abajo?

Tags: android, android-studio, slide

**Introducción:**

Este error me pasa únicamente con un solo RecyclerView de mi aplicación (la cual tiene más de 10 recyclers views). Explorando el código, no logro encontrar el motivo de esto.

**Explicación:**

Tengo una actividad la cual tiene un RecyclerView match parent (width) match parent (height). Dentro de él hay varios elementos, por lo que estos quedan por debajo de la actividad, entonces la única forma de visualizarlos es deslizando el RecyclerView.
El problema está acá porque quiero deslizarlo pero no se puede.

**Código XML de mi actividad:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Código JAVA del recycler view**

```
public class fragment extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView recycler_view;

private ArrayList<model_recycler_view> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
private adapter_recycler_view adaptador_recycler_view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    recycler_view = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    DividerItemDecoration did = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    did.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_recycler_view));

    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recycler_view.addItemDecoration(did);

    arraylist.clear();
    llenarRecycler();
    adaptador_recycler_view = new adapter_recycler_view(arraylist,getActivity());
    recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter_recycler_view);

    return view;
}
}
```

**Adjunto imágen de como se ve mi RecyclerView que contiene 7 vistas, pero solo se llega a ver hasta la 6 y no puedo seguir descendiendo hacia la 7.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Agradezco mucho su lectura!**

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un screenshot de lo que actualmente ves en tu app? Para darme también una idea qué puede ser en base a tu código.

Comment: Agrega esta propiedad a tu RV: **`android:scrollbars="vertical"`**  Si aún no te funciona, dejando esa propiedad, prueba a meter el RV dentro de un `LinearLayout`

Comment: Si hay cosas detras del recycler nunca se van a ver porque aunque tenga scroll, tambien tiene color de fondo y tapara todo.

Comment: Modifiqué mi pregunta agregándole la imágen de como se ve Fernando Torres. Tu solución no me funcionó A. Cedano. Detrás del recycler no hay nada Erick Silva. Gracias a todos por responder!

Comment: Y cuál es el Adapter podrías subir un link de github para réplicar tu problema

Comment: prueba quitar los tres constraints y/o agregar app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottom="parent"

Comment: No funcionó :(((

Comment: Intenta asignar 
`recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuidado con poner ViewGroups o vistas innecesarias en el código, tienen un coste ;) En este caso, como dentro del ConstraintLayout sólo tienes una RecyclerView, puedes borrar el ConstraintLayout y añadir el esquema de los recursos en la propia RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:listitem="@layout/your_item_view" />
```

De todas formas, para que funcionara tu ejemplo, habría que definir la constraint:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Y después modificar el width y el height, de match_parent a 0dp, que es el equivalente a match_constraint:

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! funcionó.